# Resizing a widget with CSS

Tags: html, css, dynamic, web-deployment

I am making a calendar widget but I am having issues trying to dynamically change the size of the widget. I want it to work so that no matter what the size of the web page it will work. I have had limited success with changing some part of the code but I am struggling to get the entire widget to work with what I want
I would really appreciate any help.

Here is the CSS code I am working with

```
html{
    height:100%;
}

body{
    background: #e0e0e0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#cal{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
     margin:50px auto; 
     width:100%;
    font:12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;
    display:table;

}

#cal .header {
    cursor:default;
    background: #cd310d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d));
    height:32px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0 #87260C;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cal .header span{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 34px;
}
#cal .header .hook{
    width: 9px;
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60%;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    background: #ececec;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right top, #fff, #827e7d);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#fff), to(#827e7d));
    box-shadow:0px 12px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 12px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 12px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
.right.hook{
    right:15%;
}
.left.hook{
    left:15%;
}
#cal .header .button{
    width:24px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}
#cal .header .left.button{
    left:0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-right:1px solid #ae2A0c;
}
#cal .header .right.button{
    right:0;
    top:0;
    border-left:1px solid #ae2a0c;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
#cal .header .button:hover {
    background: -mox-linear-gradient(top, #d94215, #bb330f);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top. left bottom, from(#d94215), to(#bb330f)); 

}
#cal .header .month-year{
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#cal table{
    background: #fff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#cal td{
    color:#2b2b2b;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    cursor:default;
}
#cal #days td{
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%
    color:#9e9e9e;
}
#cal #days td:not(:last-child){
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
#cal #cal-frame td.today{
    background: #ededed;
    color:#8c8c8c;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
}
#cal #cal-frame td:not(.nil):hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: #6C1A07 0px -1px;
    background:#CD310D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #3cd310d);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d));
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span{
    font-size:80%;
    position:relative;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span:first-child{
    bottom:5px;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span:last-child{
    top:5px;
}
```

Comment: Add your html too it'll be helpful

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]